# How can I use custom "class"(function) as array datatype in javascript?

Tags: javascript, customization

I know in javascript if I want define an array,I use:

```
var arr=new array();
```

However,this array could only use for store date,int,string,just the javascript already defined

Suppose I have already my custom datatype:

```
        function LayerInfo(uuid, top, left, index, pindex) {
            this.uuid = uuid;
            this.top = top;
            this.left = left;
            this.index = index;
            this.pindex = pindex;
        }
```

How can I initialize an array which the data type is the "LayerInfo",could store the "LayerInfo"?

like

```
var l=new LayerInfo()?
```

if this could be done ,how can I let the layerinfo push into the array,or pull it out?

Comment: if you want to create an array you should use `var arr = [];`. Arrays can hold instances of *any* type. What is your question?

Comment: ***this array could only use for store ... javascript already defined***... says who? Have you *tried* to put your `LayerInfo` instance in that array?* You might be surprised!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However,this array could only use for store date,int,string,just the
>   javascript already defined

Fortunately not, `arr` can store any object you like, including instances of your `LayerInfo`:

```
var arr = new Array(); //note caps or var arr = [];
arr[i] = new LayerInfo();
arr[i] = someLaterInfoInstance;
arr.push(new LayerInfo()); ...
```

Comment: This is why I love javascript :-)